# contacts where name = email

Tags: contacts

I inherited an installation where a predecessor imported an email list of 70K records and populated the Contact Name AND the Email address with the email address.

How can I isolate, export, and remove them?

Warning: noob alert.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to S.E. and CiviCRM. Having Contacts without First and Last is quite common and is often done intentionally to get Contacts signed up for Mailing Lists. If a contact has no First or Last then it is correct that the email shows as their Display Name and their Sort Name.

That said, if you really want to find and destroy/cull, then Search Builder (under Search) is your friend as it offers a Filter for 'IS NULL or IS Empty' hence you should be able to do something like the following

Individual > First Name > Is NUll (or empty)
Individual > Last Name > Is NUll (or empty)

From the Actions tab you can then Export them, and then Delete them

Answer (score 2):

If the First or Last Name field has been populated with the email address do a Search Builder search, and select the appropriate field and search for %@% using the Like operator.

Individual > First Name > Like > %@%